# How can I know the growth of the tablespace in a certain time?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, database-administration

I would like to know if there is a query that allows me to see the growth of the tablespace by a certain time (either by day, week, month or year), also if there is any query that allows me to see the changes that have generated growth on the database.

What I do to be able to see the current size of the tablespace is the next:

```
SELECT  df.tablespace_name "Tablespace",
   df.bytes / (1024 * 1024) "Size (MB)",
   SUM(fs.bytes) / (1024 * 1024) "Free (MB)",
   Nvl(Round(SUM(fs.bytes) * 100 / df.bytes),1) "% Free",
   Round((df.bytes - SUM(fs.bytes)) * 100 / df.bytes) "% Used"
FROM dba_free_space fs,
   (SELECT tablespace_name,SUM(bytes) bytes
      FROM dba_data_files
     GROUP BY tablespace_name) df
WHERE fs.tablespace_name (+)  = df.tablespace_name
GROUP BY df.tablespace_name,df.bytes
UNION ALL
SELECT df.tablespace_name tspace,
   fs.bytes / (1024 * 1024),
   SUM(df.bytes_free) / (1024 * 1024),
   Nvl(Round((SUM(fs.bytes) - df.bytes_used) * 100 / fs.bytes), 1),
   Round((SUM(fs.bytes) - df.bytes_free) * 100 / fs.bytes)
FROM dba_temp_files fs,
   (SELECT tablespace_name,bytes_free,bytes_used
      FROM v$temp_space_header
     GROUP BY tablespace_name,bytes_free,bytes_used) df
WHERE fs.tablespace_name (+)  = df.tablespace_name
GROUP BY df.tablespace_name,fs.bytes,df.bytes_free,df.bytes_used
ORDER BY 4 DESC;
```

Comment: Why not generate a report daily and monitor them over a period of time?

Comment: Because I need to show information of historical growth of the tablespace in a short time, that is why I do the query.